# Explanation of the proof of absolute convergence of $ \zeta(s, a) $

Tags: proof-explanation, uniform-convergence, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, absolute-convergence

Here is Theorem 12.1 of Introduction to Analytic Number Theory by Apostol -

> Theorem 12.1 The series for $ \zeta(s, a) $ converges absolutely for $ \sigma > 1 $. The convergence is uniform in every half-plane $ \sigma \ge 1 + \delta $, $ \delta > 0 $, so $ \zeta(s, a) $ is an analytic function of $ s $ in the half-plane $ \sigma > 1 $.
>
> Proof. All these statements follow from the inequalities
>
> $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |(n + a)^{-s}| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n + a)^{-\sigma} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n + a)^{-(1 + \delta)}. \tag*{$\Box$}$$

How does this proof work? The last sum on the right is

$$
\frac{1}{(1 + a)^{\delta + 1}} + \frac{1}{(2 + a)^{\delta + 1}} + \frac{1}{(3 + a)^{\delta + 1}} + \dots.
$$

where $ \delta > 0 $ and $ 0 < a < 1 $. Why does this converge? I can't find anything in the preceding sections or chapters that explain why this must converge. How can we show that this sum converges?

Comment: Hint: $n+a \geq n$ if $a \geq 0$. Do you known the convergence properties of $\sum n^{-p}$?

Comment: @Gary Since $ \sum n^{-\sigma} $ converges for $ \sigma > 1 $, it follows from that $ \sum n^{-p} $ must also converge for prime $ p $. But how do we show that $ \sum n^{-\sigma} $ converges for $ \sigma > 1 $?

Comment: You probably know that $\int_a^\infty x^{-(1+\delta)} dx < \infty.$ The convergence of the series follows as the integral is bounding the series from above.

Comment: @LoneLearner Sorry, by $p$ I meant a positive real number. See the hint by LurchiDerLurch.